# How to store the data from a dynamic table to database

Tags: javascript, java, database, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to figure out how to store the data from a dynamic table to the database.

Here's the idea: I'm developing a system to control the drivers journey. It basically will store the day work of the driver, spliting it on differente intervals, such as: Driving time, meal time, waiting time, etc (all of them in HH:MM). They will be adding in different tables, as the following picture shows.

[Journey Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAJnp.png)

The input data (hour), for each table, can be different. It will depend on the driver's day journey. I need to catch and store those hours on a database.

My best idea is to get all those hours after the user ends the input, but how do I store that if I don't have the field's name?

Additional information: I'm using Java, SpringBoot and Thymeleaf to develop it.

```js
JourneyControl.RegisterHourJourney = (function() {
    var counterDriving = 0;
    var counterInterval = 0;
    var counterMeal = 0;
    var counterWaiting = 0;
    var counterRest = 0;

    function RegisterJourneyHour() {
        this.novaDrivingBtn = $('.js-add-new-direcao');
        this.novoIntervalBtn = $('.js-add-new-intervalo');
        this.novaMealBtn = $('.js-add-new-refeicao');
        this.novaWaitingBtn = $('.js-add-new-espera');
        this.novoRestBtn = $('.js-add-new-pernoite');

        this.deleteDrivingBtn = $('#direcaot');
        this.deleteIntervalBtn = $('#intervalot');
        this.deleteMealBtn = $('#refeicaot');
        this.deleteWaitingBtn = $('#esperat');
        this.deleteRestBtn = $('#pernoitet');
    }

    RegisterHourJourney.prototype.start = function() {
        this.novaDrivingBtn.on('click', onAdicionarHourDriving.bind());
        this.novoIntervalBtn.on('click', onAdicionarHourInterval.bind());
        this.novaMealBtn.on('click', onAdicionarHourMeal.bind());
        this.novaWaitingBtn.on('click', onAdicionarHourWaiting.bind());
        this.novoRestBtn.on('click', onAdicionarHourRest.bind());

        this.deleteDrivingBtn.on('click', '.js-delete-btn',
                onDeleteHourDriving.bind());
        this.deleteIntervalBtn.on('click', '.js-delete-btn',
                onDeleteHourInterval.bind());
        this.deleteMealBtn.on('click', '.js-delete-btn',
                onDeleteHourMeal.bind());
        this.deleteWaitingBtn.on('click', '.js-delete-btn',
                onDeleteHourWaiting.bind());
        this.deleteRestBtn.on('click', '.js-delete-btn',
                onDeleteHourRest.bind());
    }

    function onAdicionarHourDriving() {
        /*var newRow = $("<tr id=\" " + + counterDriving + " \">");*/       
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        var inputInicio = $('#inicioDirecao').val();
        var inputFim = $('#fimDirecao').val();
        var direcao = $('#direcao').val();

        if (!inputInicio || !inputFim) {
            alert('Os campos início e fim devem ser preenchidos.');
        } else if (inputInicio.length != 5 || inputFim.length != 5) {
            alert('Preencha as horas corretamente (HH:MM).');
        } else {
            cols += '<td>' + inputInicio + '</td>';
            cols += '<td>' + inputFim + '</td>';
            cols += '<td class="text-center"><a class="  btn btn-link btn-xs js-tooltip js-delete-btn" title="Delete" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("#direcaot").append(newRow);
            counterDriving++;
            $('#inicioDirecao').val('');
            $('#fimDirecao').val('');
        }
    }

    function onAdicionarHourInterval() {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        var inputInicio = $('#inicioIntervalo').val();
        var inputFim = $('#fimIntervalo').val();

        if (!inputInicio || !inputFim) {
            alert('Os campos início e fim devem ser preenchidos.');
        } else if (inputInicio.length != 5 || inputFim.length != 5) {
            alert('Preencha as horas corretamente (HH:MM).');
        } else {
            cols += '<td>' + inputInicio + '</td>';
            cols += '<td>' + inputFim + '</td>';
            cols += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs js-tooltip js-delete-btn" title="Delete" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("#intervalot").append(newRow);
            counterInterval++;
            $('#inicioIntervalo').val('');
            $('#fimIntervalo').val('');
        }
    }

    function onAdicionarHourMeal() {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        var inputInicio = $('#inicioRefeicao').val();
        var inputFim = $('#fimRefeicao').val();

        if (!inputInicio || !inputFim) {
            alert('Os campos início e fim devem ser preenchidos.');
        } else if (inputInicio.length != 5 || inputFim.length != 5) {
            alert('Preencha as horas corretamente (HH:MM).');
        } else {
            cols += '<td>' + inputInicio + '</td>';
            cols += '<td>' + inputFim + '</td>';
            cols += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs js-tooltip js-delete-btn" title="Delete" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("#refeicaot").append(newRow);
            counterMeal++;
            $('#inicioRefeicao').val('');
            $('#fimRefeicao').val('');
        }
    }

    function onAdicionarHourWaiting() {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        var inputInicio = $('#inicioEspera').val();
        var inputFim = $('#fimEspera').val();

        if (!inputInicio || !inputFim) {
            alert('Os campos início e fim devem ser preenchidos.');
        } else if (inputInicio.length != 5 || inputFim.length != 5) {
            alert('Preencha as horas corretamente (HH:MM).');
        } else {
            cols += '<td>' + inputInicio + '</td>';
            cols += '<td>' + inputFim + '</td>';
            cols += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs js-tooltip js-delete-btn" title="Delete" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("#esperat").append(newRow);
            counterWaiting++;
            $('#inicioEspera').val('');
            $('#fimEspera').val('');
        }
    }

    function onAdicionarHourRest() {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        var inputInicio = $('#inicioPernoite').val();
        var inputFim = $('#fimPernoite').val();

        if (!inputInicio || !inputFim) {
            alert('Os campos início e fim devem ser preenchidos.');
        } else if (inputInicio.length != 5 || inputFim.length != 5) {
            alert('Preencha as horas corretamente (HH:MM).');
        } else {
            cols += '<td>' + inputInicio + '</td>';
            cols += '<td>' + inputFim + '</td>';
            cols += '<td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs js-tooltip js-delete-btn" title="Delete" href="#" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("#pernoitet").append(newRow);
            counterRest++;
            $('#inicioPernoite').val('');
            $('#fimPernoite').val('');
        }
    }

    function onDeleteHourDriving() {
        var item = document.activeElement;
        item.closest("tr").remove();
        counterDriving -= 1;
    }

    function onDeleteHourInterval() {
        var item = document.activeElement;
        item.closest("tr").remove();
        counterInterval -= 1;
    }

    function onDeleteHourMeal() {
        var item = document.activeElement;
        item.closest("tr").remove();
        counterMeal -= 1;
    }

    function onDeleteHourWaiting() {
        var item = document.activeElement;
        item.closest("tr").remove();
        counterWaiting -= 1;
    }

    function onDeleteHourRest() {
        var item = document.activeElement;
        item.closest("tr").remove();
        counterRest -= 1;
    }

    return RegisterHourJourney;
}());

$(function() {
    var RegisterHourJourney = new JourneyControl.RegisterHourJourney();
    RegisterHourJourney.start();
});
```

```html
<body>
 <section layout:fragment="conteudo">
  <div class="page-header">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-10">
      <h1>Journey Control</h1>
      <!-- <h1 th:if="${empresa.nova}">Cadastrar jornada</h1> -->
      <!-- <h1 th:unless="${empresa.nova}" th:text="|Editar empresa - ${empresa.razaoSocial}|">Editar jornada</h1> -->
     </div>

     <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="aw-page-header-controls">
       <!-- <a class="btn btn-default" th:href="@{/empresas}"> -->
       <a class="btn btn-default">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Search Journey</span>
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
   <!-- <form method="POST" th:object="${jornada}" class="form-vertical  js-form-loading"
    th:action="${empresa.nova} ? @{/empresas/nova} : @{/empresas/{codigo}(codigo=${empresa.codigo})}"> -->
   <form class="form-vertical js-form-loading">
    
    <!-- <cj:message/> -->
    
    <!-- <input type="hidden" th:field="*{codigo}" /> -->

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-2 form-group field-required">
      <label for="data" class="control-label">Date</label>
      <input id="data" type="text" class="form-control js-date" />
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-sm-5 form-group field-required">
      <label for="motorista" class="control-label">Driver</label>
      <input id="motorista" type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" />
     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-1 form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Day off</label>
      <div>
       <input type="checkbox" class="js-status" data-size="small" data-off-color="danger"
         data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="No" />
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
      <fieldset class="fieldset-border">
       <legend class="legend-border">Driving Time</legend>

       <div class="form-group row">
        <!-- <label for="inicioDirecao" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Start</label> -->
        <label for="inicioDirecao" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Start</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input id="inicioDirecao" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
         <input type="hidden" value="DIRECAO"/>
        </div>

        <label for="EndDirecao" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">End</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input id="EndDirecao" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
         <input type="hidden" value="DIRECAO"/>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
         <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary js-add-new-direcao">Add</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="table-responsive bw-tabela-simples col-sm-10">
         <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>End</th>
            <th></th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="direcaot">
           
          </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
       </div>
      </fieldset>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
      <fieldset class="fieldset-border">
       <legend class="legend-border">Driving Interval</legend>

       <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inicioIntervalo" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Start</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input id="inicioIntervalo" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
         <input type="hidden" value="INTERVALO"/>
        </div>

        <label for="EndIntervalo" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">End</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input id="EndIntervalo" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
         <input type="hidden" value="INTERVALO"/>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
         <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary js-add-new-intervalo">Add</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="table-responsive bw-tabela-simples col-sm-10">
         <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>End</th>
            <th></th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="intervalot">
           
          </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
       </div>
      </fieldset>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
      <fieldset class="fieldset-border">
       <legend class="legend-border">Meal</legend>

       <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inicioRefeicao" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Start</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input id="inicioRefeicao" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
         <input type="hidden" value="REFEICAO"/>
        </div>

        <label for="EndRefeicao" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">End</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input id="EndRefeicao" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
         <input type="hidden" value="REFEICAO"/>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
         <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary js-add-new-refeicao">Add</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="table-responsive bw-tabela-simples col-sm-10">
         <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>End</th>
            <th></th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="refeicaot">
           
          </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
       </div>
      </fieldset>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
      <fieldset class="fieldset-border">
       <legend class="legend-border">Waiting Time</legend>

       <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inicioEspera" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Start</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input id="inicioEspera" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
         <input type="hidden" value="ESPERA"/>
        </div>

        <label for="EndEspera" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">End</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input id="EndEspera" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
         <input type="hidden" value="ESPERA"/>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
         <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary js-add-new-espera">Add</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="table-responsive bw-tabela-simples col-sm-10">
         <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>End</th>
            <th></th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="esperat">
           
          </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
       </div>
      </fieldset>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
      <fieldset class="fieldset-border">
       <legend class="legend-border">Rest</legend>

       <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inicioPernoite" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Start</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input id="inicioPernoite" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
         <input type="hidden" value="PERNOITE"/>
        </div>

        <label for="EndPernoite" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">End</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <input id="EndPernoite" type="text" class="form-control js-hora">
         <input type="hidden" value="PERNOITE"/>
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
         <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary js-add-new-pernoite">Add</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="table-responsive bw-tabela-simples col-sm-10">
         <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>End</th>
            <th></th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="pernoitet">
           
          </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
       </div>
      </fieldset>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <button class="btn  btn-primary" type="submit">Salvar</button>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </section>
 <th:block layout:fragment="javascript-extra">
  <script th:src="@{/javascripts/jornada.mascara-horas.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{/javascripts/vendors/bootstrap-switch.min.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{/javascripts/cadastro_jornada.js}"></script>
  <script>
   $('.js-status').bootstrapSwitch();
  </script>
  
 </th:block>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example for meals:

When you add a new row, give it a name in the way of `name="meal[" + nextMeal + "]"`, this nomenclature will map your new meal to a list of meals in the controller on form submission.

To know what's the proper value for nextMeal, do something like this:

```
var nextMeal = 0;           
while($("tr[name='nextMeal[" + nextMeal + "]']").length){
    nextMeal++;
}
```